# Noun to describe something which evokes emotion

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

Is there a noun that can be used to described an object or idea's ability to evoke emotion? I'm currently using 'inducer', but it feels a little off.

For example:

> As a universal *inducer* of emotion, music is a potent cure for loneliness.

Comment: deleting 'noun' request and leaving single word requests may generate more answers

Comment: 'Prompter' of emotion.

Comment: What's not to like about *emotive*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elicitor is an option.  The definition fits your context.

Comment: "trigger" is an in-word right now

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a noun that can be used to described an object or idea's ability to evoke emotion?

You've asked for a word that covers *ability to evoke emotion*, but then in your example you include the word *emotion*, so it sounds like you just need a word for the *ability to evoke*? In this case *source* would work pretty well:

> As a universal *source* of emotion, music is a potent cure for loneliness.

But if you wanted a word that covered the whole bit:

> As a universal *xxxxxxx*, music is a potent cure for loneliness.

I can't think of a word that does all of that :-/ but if there is, I'd love to know it.